# sh: 2: source: not found

Tags: source, sh

I am having a problem with the installation of Armitage in Ubuntu 14.04 
I have followed this link and everything is Okey 
http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt/

But the last line would not pass :(

```
sudo sh -c "echo export MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/opt/metasploit-framework/database.yml >> /etc/profile
source /etc/profile"
```

it says :

**sh: 2: source: not found**

and that's generate an error ( could not find database ) while launching Armitage.

Please help me,
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your command above is a little bit strange. Is it two commands or one?

If one command, then `source` itself is a command. If you want to use it there, then you should give `&&` (command after `&&` will be executed next to before command) before `source`.

If two commands, then your quotation marks probably incorrect. The correct form of your commands will be:

#### First command

```
sudo sh -c "echo export MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/opt/metasploit-framework/database.yml >> /etc/profile"
```

**Explanation:** this command does concatenation (text insertion) with the text "*export MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/opt/metasploit-framework/database.yml*" into your /etc/profile. The text will be placed at new line.

#### Second command

```
source /etc/profile
```

**Explanation:** this command tells bash to use configuration inside the new /etc/profile.

Take care about the **quotation marks**. CMIIW.

Answer (score 2):

Following [Installing Metasploit Framework on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS  to 14.04 LTS and Debian 7](http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt/) documentation, the step that you are doing in the installation process is:

> Create and environment variable so it is loaded by Armitage and by
>   msfconsole when running and load the variable in to your current
>   shell:
>
> sudo sh -c "echo export
>   MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/opt/metasploit-framework/database.yml >>
>   /etc/profile
>
> source /etc/profile"

Unfortunately there is an error and should be corrected in:

> sudo sh -c "echo export
>   MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/opt/metasploit-framework/database.yml >>
>   /etc/profile"
>
> source /etc/profile